# can not add image on html option tags

Tags: html, css, image, combobox, html-select

I`m trying to use image on html option tag 
I tried this code:

```
<select class="lang_menu">
     <option value="ka">ქართული</option>
     <option value="ru">русский</option>
     <option value="en">English</option>
</select>
```

and CSS code:

```
select .lang_menu option {
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:bottom left;
   padding-left:30px;}
select .lang_menu option[value="ka"] {
   background-image:url(../image/geo.png);
}
select .lang_menu option[value="ru"] {
   background-image:url(../image/rus.png);
}
select .lang_menu option[value="en"] {
   background-image:url(../image/eng.png);
}
```

but nothing happened.
my combobox must be like this:

[image: combobox]

My image size is 16px X 11px

I don't want to use any javascript.

Comment: look like you have to use some custom select element, some plugins have been already written for you, so using plugin is also a good choice.

Comment: This question has lots on information on the limits of CSS for select dropdowns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: The image does not correspond to the code (the image has a country menu, the code has a language menu).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without jQuery , if you can achieve background image in firefox , you can't achieve it on chrome and any other browser because they simply don't support it.

Refer this [link](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and see last example its exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

try  this. Hope this help you. (not tested)

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
    -moz-padding-end: 20px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
    -moz-padding-start: 2px;
    background-color: #F07575; /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
    background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5, #F4F4F4); /* For Chrome and Safari */
    background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5, #F4F4F4); /* For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
    background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5, #F4F4F4); /* For pre-releases of IE 10*/
    background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.png), -o-linear-gradient(top, #E5E5E5, #F4F4F4); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
    background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, #E5E5E5, #F4F4F4); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    color: #555;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: this is not what the OP wants. He wants to set different background image for each ***option***. It's interesting that someone upvoted this answer.

Comment: thank you all. I done this with JQXWIDGETS.